# grails calendar reset

Tags: grails, calendar

I installed calendar Version 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT in grails and working good .
But facing one Issue :

When click on cancel button i was doing form reset .**but the calendar field is becoming clear and not reseting to default date** .

```
<g:form url="${response}" id="program" name="program" method="post">
<calendar:datePicker name="startDate" id="startDate" defaultValue="${program.startDate}" dateFormat="%Y-%m-%d"/>
<input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick = 'reset_form(this)' />
</g:form>

function reset_form(this_)
{
    document.getElementById('program').reset();
}
```

any one have idea  please ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this issue as far as I can see. Either correct the typo inside your JavaScript and refer to the correct id of your form (`program` not `new_program`) or use the standard reset button for forms `<input type="reset" .../>` instead of your javascript solution.